# Python for loop and if to find string in text

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement

I would like to use for loop and if to find out the elements in emptylists that are also in tollroad and append the elements in tollroad into a new list Tollroads

```
tollroad = ['Aberdeen Tunnel', 'Lion Rock Tunnel', 'Shing Mun Tunnels','Tseung Kwan O Tunnel', 'Tsing Sha Highway','Cross Harbour Tunnel',
'Eastern Harbour Crossing','Western Harbour Crossing', 'Tate\'s Cairn Tunnel', 'Tai Lam Tunnel', 'Lantau Link']

Emptylists = ['租庇利街 Jubilee Street', '德輔道中 Des Voeux Road Central', '摩利臣街 Morrison Street', '干諾道西 Connaught Road West','西區海底隧道 Western Harbour Crossing', '西九龍公路 West Kowloon Highway', '海寶路 Hoi Po Road', '海寶路 Hoi Po Road','連翔道 Lin Cheung Road','荔寶路 Lai Po Road',]
```

My code is below but nothing is created:

Emptylists

```
tollroad = ['Aberdeen Tunnel', 'Lion Rock Tunnel', 'Shing Mun Tunnels','Tseung Kwan O Tunnel', 'Tsing Sha Highway','Cross Harbour Tunnel',
'Eastern Harbour Crossing','Western Harbour Crossing', 'Tate\'s Cairn Tunnel', 'Tai Lam Tunnel', 'Lantau Link']

Tollroads=[]
for Emptylist in Emptylists:
  if Emptylist in tollroad:
    Tollroads.append(tollroad)
Tollroads
```

Comment: There are no items that are in both `tollroad` and `Emptylists`, so nothing passes your `if` check.  For the `in` operator to work, the strings need to be *exact* matches; the closest that you have is suffix matches.  If you want to copy suffix matches into `Tollroads`, then you'll need to write your code differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your check `if Emptylist in tollroad` is incorrect. You should check if `Emptylist` contains *any* of the `tollroad`s. Also, your variable names are awkward, do not start variable names with a capital letter.

```
[road for road in Emptylists if any(tr in road for tr in tollroad)]
#['西區海底隧道 Western Harbour Crossing']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach would be to use data normalization and set operations:

1. Normalize data

   ```
   import re
   def normalize_name(text):
       # remove leading non-latin characters if present
       return ''.join(re.split('([A-Z])', text, 1)[1:]).lower()
   ```
2. Then `set.intersection` operation can be used.

   ```
   >>> tollroad = ['Aberdeen Tunnel', 'Lion Rock Tunnel', 'Shing Mun Tunnels','Tseung Kwan O Tunnel', '
   ... Tsing Sha Highway','Cross Harbour Tunnel',
   ... 'Eastern Harbour Crossing','Western Harbour Crossing', 'Tate\'s Cairn Tunnel', 'Tai Lam Tunnel',
   ...  'Lantau Link']
   ...
   ... Emptylists = ['???? Jubilee Street', '???? Des Voeux Road Central', '???? Morrison S
   ... treet', '???? Connaught Road West','?????? Western Harbour Crossing', '????? West
   ...  Kowloon Highway', '??? Hoi Po Road', '??? Hoi Po Road','??? Lin Cheung Road','??? L
   ... ai Po Road',]

   >>> tollroad = set(normalize_name(name) for name in tollroad)

   >>> Emptylists = set(normalize_name(name) for name in Emptylists)

   >>> tollroad.intersection(Emptylists)
   {'western harbour crossing'}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you set out to do.  I agree, wouldn't mix caps in variables, unless they signify extra importance.

```
Tollroads = []
for Emptylist in Emptylists:
    head, tail = Emptylist .split(' ', 1)
    if tail in tollroad: Tollroads .append( tail )

print( Tollroads )
```